# API 28: BroadcastReceiver onReceive never executing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-sms

My onReceive is never executed. I've tried following guides online including from the official site. I'm testing on a virtual API 28 device. I understand that some of the `GUI`-related code might be wrong, but I should at least get a log output right? What am I missing?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.receivesms">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".SMSReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Receiver, the first Log.D doesn't even execute:

```
 public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MESS", intent.getAction());
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            SmsMessage[] msgs;
            String message;
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length;i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], bundle.getString("format"));
                message = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                Log.d("MESS", message);
                ((EditText) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null)
                        .findViewById(R.id.editText)).append(msgs[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress()
                        + "\n" + message + "\n");
            }
            abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        requestSmsPermission();
    }

    private void requestSmsPermission() {
        String permission = Manifest.permission.READ_SMS;
        int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permission_list = new String[1];
            permission_list[0] = permission;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("", "Permission granted");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestSmsPermission();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: do you have another app like go sms installed on your phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual problem is in the **SMS PERMISSION**. You only request `READ_SMS` Permission from user not `RECEIVE_SMS` permission. You also have to give this permission to achieve this.

```
Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
```

Try adding this:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, 1);
```

It looks like:

```
private void requestSmsPermission() {
    String readSms = Manifest.permission.READ_SMS;
    String receiveSms = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS;

    int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, readSms) + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, receiveSms);
    if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{readSms, receiveSms}, 1);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("", "Permission granted");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to increase the priority so that your app receives the SMS first, I would set it to max:

```
 <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
```